# Rename variables using resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

Is there anyway to rename only references to a variable with reshaper?
Even with "Search in comments and string literal" deselected, resharper tries searching all files for a variable name including JS and HTML files, this causes it to take considerably longer than the simple rename build into visual studio.

If it is not possible to prevent it from searching all files then how can I switch the F2 shortcut back to the visual studio built in rename.

Thank you

Comment: Please go through and select answers to your previous questions by clicking the empty check mark next to the correct answer. Please do this before asking any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of a work around that you can do for this, but you must have at least version 2016.3.

Go to:

> ReSharper >> Options >> Code Editing >> Third-Party Code

Then you can ignore files, folders, or a few other nifty options. This doesn't completely do what you're asking, but for files you never expect to touch or edit (at least with ReSharper) then you can add those files there and they will be ignored when you try to rename something.